# Plug-in for Visual Studio for quick-searching files in solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resources, solution-explorer

I want to write an Add-In for Visual Studio that provides instant search for the solution explorer. So you press a key combination and while you are typing a list first containing all files of the solution explorer gets narrowed down.

But how can I get access to the solution explorer using C#? Does anyone have some good resources?

---

Edit: I edited the title, so that it more relates to the content, since all of you posted already made plug-ins.

Comment: I'm so glad you asked this question.  I've been looking for a plug-in like this for a while but didn't think to post on SO.

Comment: Thanks j0rd4n!
I have never heard of some plug-in like this before, so I just thought about asking! I'm glad it was helpful to you!

Comment: isnt it exactly phat-studio ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Sonic File Finder](http://jens-schaller.de/sonictools/sonicfilefinder/index.htm) it's free

When you hit the shortcut you have a search box with autocomplete:
[alt text http://jens-schaller.de/files/images/SonicFileFinder/sonicFileFinderToolWindow.png](http://jens-schaller.de/files/images/SonicFileFinder/sonicFileFinderToolWindow.png)

Comment: I just tried this and it works great!  I chose this over CodeRush Express because CodeRush doesn't play well with my ViEmu shortcuts.  Sonic File Finder does exactly what it advertises (one thing and one thing well).

Comment: Sadly, the download link is broken at the moment. :(

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio is already perfectly capable of doing that; just drag the "Edit.GoToFindCombo" to the toolbar, if it's not already there. (Press Ctrl+D if it is, to activate) and type ">of s" for all files starting with the letter 's'.

[image: Example of the GoToFindCombo with the 'open' command]
<sub>(source: [aaronlerch.com](http://www.aaronlerch.com/files/blog/TheTalentedMr.GoToFindCombo_F0A5/image_thumb_5.png))</sub>

The GoToFindCombo is more powerful than this though, you can set aliases ">alias $aliasHere $SomeCommand" for virtually every command in Visual Studio. For example, to make an alias for find in files you type ">alias ff Edit.FindinFiles"

Answer (score 4):

Why re-invent the wheel? DevExpress + Microsoft tied up to offer [CodeRush Express](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/) for free @ PDC2008 that does just that if I understand you correctly.

[image]

AFAIR I think the magic key combo for Jump to File is Ctrl+Alt+F and it does substring matches too. I tried it and it worked for me. Pretty nifty. Here's [the link](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL46/) to a recording in case I goofed up on the actual keystroke... some really nice tips in it.

**Update**: Wrote [a blog post](http://madcoderspeak.blogspot.com/2008/11/ide-ninja-shortcuts-with-vs2008-and.html) for those who're short of time.

Answer (score 1):

DPack really beats all of them (and moreover it's FREE).
Check out the Alt+U and Alt+M shortcuts (also I recommend others too).

Additionally I have found StudioTools to have very impressive GoTo feature if you want to jump to specific point (type member) in another file (really very fast).

NOTE: R# also has such feature but IMO it's weaker than DPack's version.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget [Workspace Whiz](http://workspacewhiz.com/) - it's free for non-commercial use. I can't live without it and just bought a licence. It does many other things too...

[image]
<sub>(source: [workspacewhiz.com](http://workspacewhiz.com/FileOpen.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Nothing Beats Productivity Tools by Microsoft and its free.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd